# Sidebands in spin-oscillator coupled devices

Tags: quantum-state, resource-request, research, quantum-optics

I am researching spin-oscillator hybrid devices (particularly those coupled to NV centers), and I have come across [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3405) paper investigating the strain field of a cantilever and its effect on the NV centre. I know the resolved sideband regime is that the resonance frequency has to be larger than the ESR spectra linewidth, but why is this necessary/important? I cannot seem to find even the smallest explanation on this.